# Run Linux command from Symfony command

Tags: php, linux, symfony, command-line-interface

How can I run a simple Linux command in a Symfony command?

E.g. I want to run `ssh username@host -p port` at the end of the command...

I've tried:

```
$input = new StringInput('ssh username@host -p port');
$this->getApplication()->run($input, $output);
```

But that throws the following exception: `The "-p" option does not exist.``

It seems to be executed in the same "context" of my Symfony command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I run a simple Linux command in a Symfony command?

First of all, try to execute a simple/plain command (`ls`) to see what happens, then move on to your special command.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

**CODE:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

**RESULT:**

```
total 36
4 drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 Jun 13  2016 .
4 drwxrwxr-x 16 me me 4096 Mar  2 09:45 ..
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 me me 2617 Feb 19  2015 .htaccess
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1203 Jun 13  2016 app.php
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1240 Jun 13  2016 app_dev.php
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 me me 1229 Jun 13  2016 app_test.php
4 drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Mar  2 17:05 bundles
4 drwxrwxr-x  2 me me 4096 Jul 24  2015 css
4 -rw-rw-r--  1 me me  106 Feb 19  2015 robots.txt
```

As you can see above, if you put the piece of code in one of your controllers for testing purposes, `ls -lsa` lists files/folders stored under `web` folder!!!

You can just do `shell_exec('ls -lsa');` as well which is what I sometimes do. e.g. `shell_exec('git ls-remote url-to-my-git-project-repo master');`

Answer (score 5):

This is the updated interface, used in Symfony 5.2. The process constructor now requires an array as input.

source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

> The Symfony\Component\Process\Process class executes a command in a
> sub-process, taking care of the differences between operating system
> and escaping arguments to prevent security issues. It replaces PHP
> functions like exec, passthru, shell_exec and system

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and I don't know much about Symfony, you have to specifiy the options before username@host. Check it here: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html

In you case:

```
'ssh -p port username@host'
```